# Handling large number of clickable rows

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm working on an Android project that has quite a few screens with upwards of 200 rows that will be clickable per screen.  The issue I am trying to figure out is how to make them all able to be clicked without adding 200 lines of

```
TableRow r1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.table_row_1);
TableRow r2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.table_row_2);
TableRow r3 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.table_row_3);
TableRow r4 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.table_row_4);

r1.setOnClickListener(listener);
r2.setOnClickListener(listener);
r3.setOnClickListener(listener);
r4.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Eventually the rows will take their id's and search the database for the value (I'm going to use each table row as a key for a value in the database to populate a column in the row) but for now I'm just trying to change the background color of the row when each one is clicked.

Questions:
How can I handle a large number of clickable rows without thousands of lines of redundant code?  Do I need to set an OnClickListener for each row or is there a better method that I am over looking?  Is there a way to do it in the XML maybe?

Comment: Are you limited to using `TableRow`, or is it possible that you use a `ListView` to show your database content?

Comment: I started using `TableRow` and haven't finalized the design yet.  I hadn't heard of `ListView` yet.  Does it have a more elegant way of handling large numbers of clickables?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view. In short, using a `ListView` allows you to fetch values from a database and display them in a scrollable view. Then for your `ListView` you can use the callback method `setOnItemClickListener()` which will trigger when you click on an item in the list.

Comment: I can write you a quick demo if you'd like

Comment: That would be great, thanks.

Comment: Was my answer helpful at any level?

Comment: Yes very helpful thanks a lot,  `ListView` is the best way to go

Comment: You are always welcome :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69509/discussion-between-dommol-and-marcus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using a `ListView` with a custom `ListAdapter`

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpComponents();
    }

    private void setUpComponents(){
        ArrayList<String> myValuesToDisplay = getDatabaseContent();
        MyCustomListAdapter adapter = new MyCustomListAdapter(this, myValuesToDisplay);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getDatabaseContent(){
        /*
        This is where you would like to connect to your database and fetch the content.
        In this example, we simulate the result by returning an ArrayList<String>
         */

        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add("Value1");
        values.add("Value2");
        values.add("Value3");
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //When you click on an item in the list view, you fetch the position in the list
        System.out.println("Clicked on item with position: " + position);
    }

}
```

MyCustomListAdapter.java:

```
public class MyCustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private ArrayList<String> yourArray;

    public MyCustomListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> yourArray){
        super(ctx, R.layout.my_custom_list_item, yourArray);
        this.yourArray = yourArray;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Re-use rows to save battery
        View row;
        if (convertView == null) {
            //We inflate our custom view for the ListView item
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            row = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.my_custom_list_item, null);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }

        //Get the current item of the array
        String arrayItem = yourArray.get(position);
        //Get the text view in the layout of which we want to display the value
        TextView tvListItem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_item);
        //Set the text
        tvListItem.setText(arrayItem);
        //Return the row to the ListView
        return row;
    }
}
```

ActivityMain.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

my_custom_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tv_list_item" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This solution will create a scrollable `ListView` and populate it with your database values. Your implementation of the `ListAdapter` can vary. You can choose what and how you would like to display by changing the layout in `my_custom_list_item.xml`.

The result:

[image: Result]

Clicking on a row will print out its position in the list. You can for example use that information to start another activity displaying detailed information about that entry.